# AWS SQL Server RDS Multi-AZ connection string

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, connection-string, failover, rds

I have an AWS RDS SQL Server RDS instance running with mirroring (Multi-AZ). Typically the mirror failover server has to be declared in the connection string as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h52hef8(v=vs.110).aspx

I can't find what the "Failover Partner" should be in the aws console.

Does aws/rds take care of this behind the scenes so i only have to declare 1 server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be handled by AWS for you using DNS changes only:

> The primary and standby instances use the same endpoint whose physical
>   network address transitions to the mirror as part of the failover
>   process, so you do not have to reconfigure your application or set up
>   multiple endpoints when a failover occurs.

From here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_SQLServer.html#SQLServer.Concepts.General.Mirroring